# Long strand of white eggs on balcony cat net - What insect do they belong to?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

In the last few weeks we've noticed multiple strands of tiny white eggs appearing on our balcony cat net. It seems that they were always laid after rainfall (we had plenty in the last few days). Old eggs were washed away and new ones appeared soon after.

The way they're arranged, I have a feeling those could be moth eggs. Or is it something else? Should we get rid of it?

p.s.: We live in southern Germany.

[image]

Comment: Possibly snail eggs. Similar posts: [what kind of hot pink eggs are these](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92166/what-kind-of-hot-pink-eggs-are-these), [what is this agglomeration of pink cells I found attached to a stone](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82344/what-is-this-agglomeration-of-pink-cells-i-found-attached-to-a-stone), [can someone identify these eggs](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76188/can-someone-identify-these-eggs/), and [what made this is it an egg sac](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/98213/what-made-this-is-it-an-egg-sac).